# query columns from many tables using dynamic SQL or Correlated Subquery on SQL Server INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, information-schema, correlated-subquery

I want to list all the `Manufacturers` identified in an SQL Server database.

There are many tables with manufacturer names in them, but they are not always in a nicely named column. However, column names *are* LIKE `%manuf%`.

So:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%manuf%' 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

gets me a list of tables I want to query from and the column name I want to query.

How can I now query the manufacturer names from those tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all of them returned in one result set you can use this query:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cmd = STUFF((
SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT '+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+' FROM '+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%manuf%' 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,11,'')
;

EXEC( @cmd);
```

That requires all of them to be a (n)varchar data type. If you run into problems add a cast:

```
SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT CAST('+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM '+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
```

This seems like a very odd database design. You might want to revisit that...

---

If `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` isn't working for you use this:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cmd = STUFF((
SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT '+QUOTENAME(c.name)+' FROM dbo.'+QUOTENAME(t.name)
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t
ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%name%' 
AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY t.name
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,11,'')
;

EXEC( @cmd);
```

While `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is part of the ANSI standard, using the SQL Server catalog views is usually the preferred way to go anyway.

---

One more thing: If `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` returns incorrect results, you might have some kind of corruption going on, you should check that by running `DBCC CHECKDB` in that database.

Comment: you said it brother, very odd. Anyway, I have now discovered that there are tables contained in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA that are actually no longer in the database, so your query fails with an Invalid object name '_name of table that has been apparently been dropped_'. Sorry, I can't verify your query on this database.

Comment: I would say there's corruption in the data base. By iterating Sebastian's solution I was able to identify the bad tables and exclude them with an AND. Here's what I finally used successfully (thanks Sebastian)

`DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cmd = STUFF((
SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT '+QUOTENAME(c.name)+' FROM dbo.'+QUOTENAME(t.name)
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t
ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%manuf%'
 AND t.name != 'badTable1'
 AND t.name != 'badTable2' 
 AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,11,'')
;

EXEC( @cmd);`